# What does `{0:X2}` mean in this code sample?

Tags: c#

In the below code sample, what does `{0:X2}` mean? This is from the reflection section of the MCTS Application Development Foundation book (covering dynamic code, etc.).

```
foreach(Byte b in body.GetILAsBodyArray())
{
Console.Write("{0:X2}", b);
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This uses the same format as String.Format().  Check out the following reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

- X = Hexadecimal format
- 2 = 2 characters

Comment: You find the `X` and the `2` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 3):

Beware the length specified is not respected if the number is too large to fit the length.

```
 long a = 123456789;
 Console.Write("{0:X2}", a);
 ->   75BCD15
```

This is especially important if you want to show negative hex numbers where all the high bits are set to 1's.

```
 long a = -1;
 Console.Write("{0:X2}", a);
 ->  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```